# Is there a support of asp by Nginx?

Tags: nginx, asp

There are a lot of asp program around and work fine. Can it be made to work with Nginx with minimal effort?

Comment: ASP or ASP.net? These are quite different animals.

Comment: What do you want to do with nginx? If you're just using nginx as a static files proxy or something, it really doesn't matter what's running on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Run / convert asp code to run on nginx? Yes

([chillisoft](http://www.gsp.com/support/virtual/web/asp/chili/), [asp2php](http://asp2php.naken.cc/), [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)....)

With "minimal Effort"? No

Where's the incentive?